# What is the TeX equivalent for the following C# nested loop?

Tags: pstricks, calculations, loops, nesting

I need a nested loop to animate PSTricks diagrams. In C# or C or C++, I usually write as follows.

```c
int N=6;
for(int x=0; x<N; x++)
    for(int y=x+1; y<N; y++)
        Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})",x,y);
```

I have attempted to do it in TeX as follows, but it does not work. :-)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand\N{6}
\newcommand\Init{}
\newcommand\Freq{}
\begin{document}
\multido{\ix=0+1}{\N}
{
        \makeatletter
            \renewcommand\Init{\strip@pt\dimexpr\ix pt + 1pt\relax}         
            \renewcommand\Freq{\strip@pt\dimexpr\N pt - \Init pt\relax}
        \makeatother
        \multido{\iy=\Init+1}{\Freq}
        {
                (\ix, \iy)\par
        }
}
\end{document}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand\N{6}
\begin{document}
\multido{\ix=0+1,\ixB=1+1,\iN=5+-1}{\N}{%
  \multido{\iy=\ixB+1}{\iN}{(\ix, \iy)\endgraf}}
\end{document}
```

and with a counter:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{multido}
\newcommand\N{6}
\newcounter{NminusOne}
\setcounter{NminusOne}{\N}\addtocounter{NminusOne}{-1}

\begin{document}
\multido{\ix=0+1,\ixB=1+1,\iN=\theNminusOne+-1}{\N}{%
  \multido{\iy=\ixB+1}{\iN}{(\ix, \iy)\endgraf}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a trick to avoid hard-coding the value 5?

Comment: define two counters for N and NminusOne, then you can use these instead of \N and 5

Comment: @Herbert: It seems useful to define `\multido` as a long macro. Is there any special reason that `\multido` isn't a long macro? If not, could you revise it to support `\par`?

Comment: @Leo: it is a really old package and only bug fixes will be done. Too many people use it in the meantime, modifications to the code may be dangerous.  You can use `\endgraf` instead and all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\edef` to expand the macro content. Using `\renewcommand` simply redefines the macro to the exact same content over and over again. That the `\ix` and `\Init` macros have a changing value doesn't matter here.
You can't have a paragraph in `\multido` because it isn't defined `\long`. So use either `\\` or hide the `\par` in a macro. You need also take care of spaces introduced by line breaks, e.g. after `}` and `{`.
The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` macros must be places outside the `\multido` macro, otherwise it's already to late to change catcodes.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand\N{6}
\newcommand\Init{}
\newcommand\Freq{}
\newcommand\mypar{\par}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\multido{\ix=0+1}{\N}{%
    \edef\Init{\strip@pt\dimexpr\ix pt + 1pt\relax}%
    \edef\Freq{\strip@pt\dimexpr\N pt - \Init pt\relax}%
    \multido{\iy=\Init+1}{\Freq}{%
        (\ix, \iy)\mypar
    }%
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: where is the sense to use `\dimexpr` when the unit is not needed?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Especially introducing me to `\edef`. It might be used in another scenario in my life. :-) Since Herbert's solution is simpler than yours so I switched the green mark to Herbert's.

Comment: @Herbert: I didn't changed that part of xport's original code, simply fixed the other issues. The code works beside that.

Comment: @xport: That's fine. You shouldn't accept answers right away anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{multido}


\newcommand{\N}{6}
\newcounter{Init}
\newcounter{Freq}
\setcounter{Freq}{\N}
\newcommand\mypar{\par}

\begin{document}
\multido{\ix=0+1}{\N}
{
    \setcounter{Init}{\ix}
    \addtocounter{Init}{1}
    \addtocounter{Freq}{-1}
    \multido{\iy=\value{Init}+1}{\value{Freq}}
    {
        (\ix, \iy)\endgraf
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

The following is the simplified version of Herbert's answer.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{multido}
\newcommand\N{6}


\newcounter{NTemp}
\setcounter{NTemp}{\N}

\begin{document}
\multido{\ix=0+1,\iTemp=1+1}{\N}
{
  \addtocounter{NTemp}{-1}
  \multido{\iy=\iTemp+1}{\theNTemp}
  {
    (\ix, \iy)\endgraf
  }
}
\end{document}
```